# How to have a timeline/gantt overview on my homepage

Tags: gantt-view

How am I able to have a gantt chart on my home page of my SharePoint?

It just keeps giving me a list of the different launches I'm looking over. I'm needing it as an overview timeline to control launches.

Answer (score 2):

Whe you are on your list page, click on "List" in the toolbar. Then Create view. Then select "Gantt View". Give it a name and select the properties you want. Ok.

On your page, you select your list, "Edit Web Part" on the top right corner of your list. Under "Selected view", choose the one you just made. And Voilà!